# Is my Arduino dead or is it just its processor?

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading, atmega328

I have a problem with my Arduino. I can't upload any sketches to it (it gives me the error `avrdude: verification error; content mismatch`), but the LEDs are still blinking. Do you think that the whole Arduino is dead or is it just the chip ?

EDIT : I tried an other USB cable but it changed nothing.

EDIT : Here is the output of verbose mode while uploading :

```
Taille binaire du croquis : 1 084 octets (d'un max de 32 256 octets)
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega328p -carduino -P/dev/cu.usbmodem641 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:/var/folders/56/7b6d3xm14n31kjrw8609ywjw0000gn/T/build1168987322216849272.tmp/Blink.cpp.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 5.11, compiled on Sep  2 2011 at 18:52:52
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/Users/trevorannedenise/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbmodem641
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
         AVR Part                      : ATMEGA328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : Arduino
         Description     : Arduino
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [80]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [81]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [04] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [82]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [04] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [98]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
         Hardware Version: 3
         Firmware Version: 4.4
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [84]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [85]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [86]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [87]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [89]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
         Vtarget         : 0.3 V
         Varef           : 0.3 V
         Oscillator      : 28.800 kHz
         SCK period      : 3.3 us

avrdude: Send: A [41] . [81]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [04] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [82]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [04] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: B [42] . [86] . [00] . [00] . [01] . [01] . [01] . [01] . [03] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [00] . [80] . [04] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [80] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: E [45] . [05] . [04] . [d7] . [c2] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: P [50]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | avrdude: Send: u [75]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] . [1e] . [95] . [0f] . [10] 
################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f
avrdude: Send: V [56] . [a0] . [03] . [fc] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: V [56] . [a0] . [03] . [fd] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: V [56] . [a0] . [03] . [fe] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: V [56] . [a0] . [03] . [ff] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: reading input file "/var/folders/56/7b6d3xm14n31kjrw8609ywjw0000gn/T/build1168987322216849272.tmp/Blink.cpp.hex"
avrdude: writing flash (1084 bytes):

Writing | avrdude: Send: U [55] . [00] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: d [64] . [00] . [80] F [46] . [0c] . [94] a [61] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] . [9d] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] $ [24] . [00] ' [27] . [00] * [2a] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] % [25] . [00] ( [28] . [00] + [2b] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
#####avrdude: Send: U [55] @ [40] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: d [64] . [00] . [80] F [46] # [23] . [00] & [26] . [00] ) [29] . [00] . [04] . [04] . [04] . [04] . [04] . [04] . [04] . [04] . [02] . [02] . [02] . [02] . [02] . [02] . [03] . [03] . [03] . [03] . [03] . [03] . [01] . [02] . [04] . [08] . [10]   [20] @ [40] . [80] . [01] . [02] . [04] . [08] . [10]   [20] . [01] . [02] . [04] . [08] . [10]   [20] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [07] . [00] . [02] . [01] . [00] . [00] . [03] . [04] . [06] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [11] $ [24] . [1f] . [be] . [cf] . [ef] . [d8] . [e0] . [de] . [bf] . [cd] . [bf] . [11] . [e0] . [a0] . [e0] . [b1] . [e0] . [ea] . [e3] . [f4] . [e0] . [02] . [c0] . [05] . [90] . [0d] . [92] . [a2] 0 [30] . [b1] . [07] . [d9] . [f7] . [11] . [e0] . [a2] . [e0] . [b1] . [e0] . [01] . [c0] . [1d] . [92] . [ab] 0 [30] . [b1] . [07] . [e1] . [f7] . [0e] . [94] . [0c] . [02] . [0c] . [94] . [1b] . [02] . [0c] . [94] . [00] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [80] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: d [64] . [00] . [80] F [46] . [80] . [91] . [00] . [01] a [61] . [e0] . [0e] . [94] . [b8] . [01] h [68] . [ee] s [73] . [e0] . [80] . [e0] . [90] . [e0] . [0e] . [94] . [e5] . [00] . [80] . [91] . [00] . [01] ` [60] . [e0] . [0e] . [94] . [b8] . [01] h [68] . [ee] s [73] . [e0] . [80] . [e0] . [90] . [e0] . [0e] . [94] . [e5] . [00] . [08] . [95] . [80] . [91] . [00] . [01] a [61] . [e0] . [0e] . [94] y [79] . [01] . [08] . [95] . [1f] . [92] . [0f] . [92] . [0f] . [b6] . [0f] . [92] . [11] $ [24] / [2f] . [93] ? [3f] . [93] . [8f] . [93] . [9f] . [93] . [af] . [93] . [bf] . [93] . [80] . [91] . [06] . [01] . [90] . [91] . [07] . [01] . [a0] . [91] . [08] . [01] . [b0] . [91] . [09] . [01] 0 [30] . [91] . [0a] . [01] . [01] . [96] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d] # [23] / [2f] - [2d] _ [5f] - [2d] 7 [37]   [20] . [f0] - [2d] W [57] . [01] . [96] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d]   [20] . [93] . [0a] . [01] . [80] . [93]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [c0] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: d [64] . [00] . [80] F [46] . [06] . [01] . [90] . [93] . [07] . [01] . [a0] . [93] . [08] . [01] . [b0] . [93] . [09] . [01] . [80] . [91] . [02] . [01] . [90] . [91] . [03] . [01] . [a0] . [91] . [04] . [01] . [b0] . [91] . [05] . [01] . [01] . [96] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d] . [80] . [93] . [02] . [01] . [90] . [93] . [03] . [01] . [a0] . [93] . [04] . [01] . [b0] . [93] . [05] . [01] . [bf] . [91] . [af] . [91] . [9f] . [91] . [8f] . [91] ? [3f] . [91] / [2f] . [91] . [0f] . [90] . [0f] . [be] . [0f] . [90] . [1f] . [90] . [18] . [95] . [9b] . [01] . [ac] . [01] . [7f] . [b7] . [f8] . [94] . [80] . [91] . [02] . [01] . [90] . [91] . [03] . [01] . [a0] . [91] . [04] . [01] . [b0] . [91] . [05] . [01] f [66] . [b5] . [a8] . [9b] . [05] . [c0] o [6f] ? [3f] . [19] . [f0] . [01] . [96] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d] . [7f] . [bf] . [ba] / [2f] . [a9] / [2f] . [98] / [2f] . [88] ' [27] . [86] . [0f] . [91] . [1d]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [00] . [01]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: d [64] . [00] . [80] F [46] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d] b [62] . [e0] . [88] . [0f] . [99] . [1f] . [aa] . [1f] . [bb] . [1f] j [6a] . [95] . [d1] . [f7] . [bc] . [01] - [2d] . [c0] . [ff] . [b7] . [f8] . [94] . [80] . [91] . [02] . [01] . [90] . [91] . [03] . [01] . [a0] . [91] . [04] . [01] . [b0] . [91] . [05] . [01] . [e6] . [b5] . [a8] . [9b] . [05] . [c0] . [ef] ? [3f] . [19] . [f0] . [01] . [96] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d] . [ff] . [bf] . [ba] / [2f] . [a9] / [2f] . [98] / [2f] . [88] ' [27] . [8e] . [0f] . [91] . [1d] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d] . [e2] . [e0] . [88] . [0f] . [99] . [1f] . [aa] . [1f] . [bb] . [1f] . [ea] . [95] . [d1] . [f7] . [86] . [1b] . [97] . [0b] . [88] ^ [5e] . [93] @ [40] . [c8] . [f2] ! [21] P [50] 0 [30] @ [40] @ [40] @ [40] P [50] @ [40] h [68] Q [51] | [7c] O [4f] ! [21] . [15] 1 [31] . [05] A [41] . [05] Q [51] . [05] q [71] . [f6] . [08] . [95] x [78] . [94] . [84] . [b5]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] @ [40] . [01]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: d [64] . [00] . [80] F [46] . [82] ` [60] . [84] . [bd] . [84] . [b5] . [81] ` [60] . [84] . [bd] . [85] . [b5] . [82] ` [60] . [85] . [bd] . [85] . [b5] . [81] ` [60] . [85] . [bd] . [ee] . [e6] . [f0] . [e0] . [80] . [81] . [81] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [e1] . [e8] . [f0] . [e0] . [10] . [82] . [80] . [81] . [82] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [80] . [81] . [81] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [e0] . [e8] . [f0] . [e0] . [80] . [81] . [81] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [e1] . [eb] . [f0] . [e0] . [80] . [81] . [84] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [e0] . [eb] . [f0] . [e0] . [80] . [81] . [81] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [ea] . [e7] . [f0] . [e0] . [80] . [81] . [84] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [80] . [81] . [82] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [80] . [81] . [81] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [80] . [81] . [80] h [68] . [80] . [83] . [10] . [92] . [c1] . [00] . [08] . [95] . [cf] . [93] . [df] . [93] H [48] / [2f] P [50] . [e0] . [ca] . [01] . [86] V [56] . [9f] O [4f]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [80] . [01]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: d [64] . [00] . [80] F [46] . [fc] . [01] 4 [34] . [91] J [4a] W [57] _ [5f] O [4f] . [fa] . [01] . [84] . [91] . [88] # [23] i [69] . [f1] . [90] . [e0] . [88] . [0f] . [99] . [1f] . [fc] . [01] . [e8] Y [59] . [ff] O [4f] . [a5] . [91] . [b4] . [91] . [fc] . [01] . [ee] X [58] . [ff] O [4f] . [c5] . [91] . [d4] . [91] f [66] # [23] Q [51] . [f4] / [2f] . [b7] . [f8] . [94] . [8c] . [91] . [93] / [2f] . [90] . [95] . [89] # [23] . [8c] . [93] . [88] . [81] . [89] # [23] . [0b] . [c0] b [62] 0 [30] a [61] . [f4] / [2f] . [b7] . [f8] . [94] . [8c] . [91] . [93] / [2f] . [90] . [95] . [89] # [23] . [8c] . [93] . [88] . [81] . [83] + [2b] . [88] . [83] / [2f] . [bf] . [06] . [c0] . [9f] . [b7] . [f8] . [94] . [8c] . [91] . [83] + [2b] . [8c] . [93] . [9f] . [bf] . [df] . [91] . [cf] . [91] . [08] . [95] H [48] / [2f] P [50] . [e0] . [ca] . [01] . [82] U [55] . [9f] O [4f] . [fc] . [01] $ [24] . [91] . [ca] . [01]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [c0] . [01]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: d [64] . [00] . [80] F [46] . [86] V [56] . [9f] O [4f] . [fc] . [01] . [94] . [91] J [4a] W [57] _ [5f] O [4f] . [fa] . [01] 4 [34] . [91] 3 [33] # [23] . [09] . [f4] @ [40] . [c0] " [22] # [23] Q [51] . [f1] # [23] 0 [30] q [71] . [f0] $ [24] 0 [30] ( [28] . [f4] ! [21] 0 [30] . [a1] . [f0] " [22] 0 [30] . [11] . [f5] . [14] . [c0] & [26] 0 [30] . [b1] . [f0] ' [27] 0 [30] . [c1] . [f0] $ [24] 0 [30] . [d9] . [f4] . [04] . [c0] . [80] . [91] . [80] . [00] . [8f] w [77] . [03] . [c0] . [80] . [91] . [80] . [00] . [8f] } [7d] . [80] . [93] . [80] . [00] . [10] . [c0] . [84] . [b5] . [8f] w [77] . [02] . [c0] . [84] . [b5] . [8f] } [7d] . [84] . [bd] . [09] . [c0] . [80] . [91] . [b0] . [00] . [8f] w [77] . [03] . [c0] . [80] . [91] . [b0] . [00] . [8f] } [7d] . [80] . [93] . [b0] . [00] . [e3] / [2f] . [f0] . [e0] . [ee] . [0f] . [ff] . [1f] . [ee] X [58] . [ff] O [4f] . [a5] . [91] . [b4] . [91] / [2f] . [b7]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [00] . [02]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: d [64] . [00] < [3c] F [46] . [f8] . [94] f [66] # [23] ! [21] . [f4] . [8c] . [91] . [90] . [95] . [89] # [23] . [02] . [c0] . [8c] . [91] . [89] + [2b] . [8c] . [93] / [2f] . [bf] . [08] . [95] . [cf] . [93] . [df] . [93] . [0e] . [94] > [3e] . [01] . [0e] . [94] . [97] . [00] . [c0] . [e0] . [d0] . [e0] . [0e] . [94] . [80] . [00]   [20] . [97] . [e1] . [f3] . [0e] . [94] . [00] . [00] . [f9] . [cf] . [f8] . [94] . [ff] . [cf] . [0d] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
### | 100% 0.21s

avrdude: 1084 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against /var/folders/56/7b6d3xm14n31kjrw8609ywjw0000gn/T/build1168987322216849272.tmp/Blink.cpp.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file /var/folders/56/7b6d3xm14n31kjrw8609ywjw0000gn/T/build1168987322216849272.tmp/Blink.cpp.hex:
avrdude: input file /var/folders/56/7b6d3xm14n31kjrw8609ywjw0000gn/T/build1168987322216849272.tmp/Blink.cpp.hex contains 1084 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | avrdude: Send: U [55] . [00] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: t [74] . [00] . [80] F [46]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
#####avrdude: Send: U [55] @ [40] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: t [74] . [00] . [80] F [46]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [80] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: t [74] . [00] . [80] F [46]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [c0] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: t [74] . [00] . [80] F [46]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [00] . [01]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: t [74] . [00] . [80] F [46]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] @ [40] . [01]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: t [74] . [00] . [80] F [46]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [80] . [01]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: t [74] . [00] . [80] F [46]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [c0] . [01]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: t [74] . [00] . [80] F [46]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [00] . [02]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: t [74] . [00] < [3c] F [46]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
### | 100% 0.16s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
         0x0c != 0xff
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch
avrdude: Send: Q [51]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Comment: Have you tried to reflash the bootloader? Is it blinking with your current sketch, or a previous sketch?

Comment: Any sketches? Does that mean you've tested something really simple, like blink? http://arduino.cc/en/tutorial/blink#.UxXkwF6IuWY

Comment: Yes I tried blink !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's possible you have a non-fatal problem

- check power
- check connections
- reflash the Arduino bootloader

If your Arduino has a socketed microcontroller you can try swapping it out with one that has the bootloader preloaded.

Comment: check the fuses as well

Comment: @zmo: checking the fuses is somewhat pointless. They're not actual fuses which can break, but PTC resistors which self-repair.

Comment: The fuses referred to control processor behaviour. They are not PTC resistors and don't self-repair. See the datasheet for the processor under the "fuses" section.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced this problem several times!
If you are using arduino UNO, make sure to remove any serial connected device on the (Tx,RX) pins. Upload your sketch, then connect them back again.
It's because the arduino UNO has on serial pins which is used for uploading the code, there will be a conflict if there was a device that is connected to the serial the same time you upload the code.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced similar problems and the solution that worked for me was to power the burning circuit with the Arduino onboard 5 volt. 3.3 Volt does work but at times it gives these errors especially while burning the bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me with a bare-bones Arduino. I disconnected everything and it still happens. I don't know what the cause is but you definitely will need to reflash the bootloader or replace the chip.

It isn't a connection or power issue, and it isn't related to having devices connected to pins 0/1 (although that can also cause problems, it will give a different error).